# C++ font path Windows

Tags: c++11, truetype

How May I get the path to a specific font in Windows. Is there a specific way to get them for all Windows versions? Or is it different for all OS's.

Example:

```
.../path/fonts/truetype/arial.ttf
```

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: [Get a font filepath from name and style in C++/Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11387564/get-a-font-filepath-from-name-and-style-in-c-windows) (SO; see also the link therein).

Option 2: [There is an API for this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762181(v=vs.85).aspx), with a CSIDL of `CSIDL_FONTS` or (for Vista and later) a KNOWNFOLDERID of `FOLDERID_Fonts`.